# Find the greatest decrease in the values and their position

Tags: matlab

I have to find the days between which the greatest temperature drop occurred for this given month.

```
    temps2 =  [NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    85;
82    75    76    81    73    71    74;
76    74    73    81    83    82    75;
72    74    75    48    43    56    69;
73    75    81    83    77    73    74;
78   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN]
```

In this case, the answer is [18 19], when the temperature dropped from 75 to 48

I changed the NaN into zeros. Then get the vertical array for the whole month. Then used the diff() function to get the difference. However, I do not have any idea what should be the next move. Moreover, since NaN=0, at the end it gives a difference -78, which should not be included. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You want to find max drop between any day? Or only consecutive days? In that way 85 to 43 drop must be maximum.

Comment: I don't understand what is `[18 19]`. These are day numbers? From what i see they correspond to temperatures 81  and  83, not to 75 and 48. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yup they are the days of the month. And it's 75 and 48. If you look at the 4th row 3rd and fourth column you will find it. First row has one day. That's date 1. 3rd row ends at day 15. 4th row 3rd column day 18.

Comment: What happens if you don't change `NaN` to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
temps2 =  [NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    85;
82    75    76    81    73    71    74;
76    74    73    81    83    82    75;
72    74    75    48    43    56    69;
73    75    81    83    77    73    74;
78   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN];

% transpose to have days row wise from left to right 
% for diff function
transposeTemps2 = temps2';

% difference in consequtive days
d = diff(transposeTemps2(:));

% find minimum value of the differences
[c, ind] = min(d);

% find number of NaN at the begining of the month
% to calculate day number where is the largest difference
noOfNaNs = find(~isnan(transposeTemps2(:)), 1,'first') - 1;


% number of the first day
firstDayFound = ind - noOfNaNs;
secondDayFound = firstDayFound + 1;

[firstDayFound secondDayFound]

ans =

    18    19
```

Comment: It worked nicely! :) Thanks!
It's my third week of using MATLAB. Can you explain me what's happening in the line bellow?
"noOfNaNs = find(~isnan(transposeTemps2(:)), 1,'first') - 1"

Comment: @user3226108 basically you use `isnan` to mark NaN in the input vector/matrix. You inverse it so that non-NaN were denoted by `1` rather then `0`, and then you look for the index of first occurrence of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert for matlab but I would like to present my idea how to solve this:
You copy your temperature in an array. If you can check if the value is NaN you don't have to change NaN to zero values. That's quite important because zero is a valid temperature and if you change the value to zero you can't decide whether the value was NaN or zero.

Now you iterate through the array and compare the current index i and i + 1. You save the position and the value of the temp difference. On further iterations you have to check if the new difference is higher than the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Being a new user could not figure it out to work!